# R Summarise Last N Columns with Dynamic Headers

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I'm trying to summarize a table that has N number of date columns that will always exist at the end of the data set.  Is there a way to summarize the last N columns instead of calling each column by name?

```
df <- df %>% group_by(Project) %>% summarise(???)
```

| Project | Sep-21 | Oct-21 | Nov-2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 5678 | 10 | 11 | 5 |
| 1234 | 23 | 1 | 87 |
| 5678 | 8 | 16 | 8 |

Expected Output:

| Project | Sep-21 | Oct-21 | Nov-2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 27 | 6 | 93 |
| 5678 | 18 | 27 | 13 |

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Project = c(1234,5678,1234,5678),
  Sep = c(4,10,23,8),
  Oct = c(5,11,1,16),
  Nov = c(6,5,87,8)
)

t(sapply(split(df, df$Project), function(x) apply(x[,-1L], 2, sum)))
```

Output

```
     Sep Oct Nov
1234  27   6  93
5678  18  27  13
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexing with `summarise` and `across` may be a bit buggy as the index have to consider the grouping column as well.  A neater approach is to `select` the columns of interest first and then do a `group_by` and use `everything()` to select the remaining columns

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
 select(Project, 7:ncol(.)) %>% 
 group_by(Project) %>% 
 summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

---

If we want to directly do without `select`, subtract the column index from the number of columns used in the `group_by` for the range

```
df %>%
    group_by(Project) %>%
    summarise(across((7-1):(ncol(.)-1), sum, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```